# Expandable custom views in ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I need to write media player in my application. According to planned design it needs to show media controllers in Action bar. Besides, one of these control should open full version of player with current track details and scrollable playlist. Expanded version should look something like this:

http://petromi.com/get/5ea6d49e3e.png

I tried to implement this with standard ActionBar, but it seems that custom view's height cannot be more than ActionBar's. Am I right?

May be it can be done other way with ActionBar or via ABS? Or I should implement my own view? What do you think?

Comment: you can use slidingdrawer for this..http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show a [`ListPopupWindow`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListPopupWindow.html) when list icon is clicked. Use that icon as anchor to place the popup as a drop-down.

After showing, you can get the `ListView` from `getListView()` and call `addHeaderView ()` on it to add a fixed View at the top of the list.

`ListView` can scroll and can have any number of entries. That'll remove the need to drag-expand it.

Comment: Seems to be a solution. Thank you!